# Doubts on the methodology used for build and evaluate a Kriging model

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, kriging

I have run 3000 finite element (deterministic) simulations of a physical model, which has 10 design variables and one output variable. I have generated the sampling plan using the LH method. My question is if the following procedure for building and evaluate a Kriging model is correct:

1. Select a random subset of the initial data set: let's say 100 samples (and its output values) from the 3000 available.
2. Split the subset randomly into two "sub-subsets" in a 70/30 proportion: one for training and the other for testing the model (70 samples for training and 30 for testing), and build the Kriging model (the estimation of its hyperparameters is made by using the minimum likelihood approach). This step will give as a result the tuned hyperparameters of the Kriging model.
3. If the testing error is above some measure, go back to step 1 and select another subset (maintaining the 100 samples or adding more samples). If not, continue to step 3.
4. Perform a k-fold cross-validation (with k=10 for instance) over the entire data set (3000 samples), using the Kriging model built in the previous step, to see how the MSE error evolve over the different folds.
5. If the computed error is above a certain level, return to step 1 and repeat the entire procedure.

Is this methodology OK?? The purpose of building a Kriging model in this case is for regression, not for optimization.

Comment: Could you explain why you are sampling?

Comment: I am sampling because I am trying to build a model capable of making acceptable generalizations over the space where the design variables lives. So, I pretended to use a "space-filling" sample method.

Comment: I believe you could approach this more effectively by studying spatial subdomains separately at the outset, investigating the possibility of nonstationarity.  If you decide the field is stationary, then consider using as much of the data as you can.  Since you are using *maximum* likelihood, there seems to be little point to the involved methodology you have described.

Answer (score -1):

Your sample size is relatively large (3000), so I think it is appropriate to skip Steps 1-3 and go straight to Step 3 but use k=100 (or whatever you number feel is more appropriate)

Comment: Ok, but in that case: the hyperparameters have to be estimated without using the Minimum Likelihood Estimation? What would be the procedure?

Comment: Sorry, where it says "minimum" must be "maximum"....